# How can I create a vector from two others, using one for the labels and one for the values?

Tags: r, vector

Let's say I have a vector `a = c("Label 1", "Label 2")` and a vector `b = c(1, 2)`. I was wondering whether there is an elegant way to create a vector `c = c("Label 1" = 1, "Label 2" = 2)` from these two. Setting `c <- c(a = b)` unfortunately doesn't do the job - but is there any way to do this with a single line of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setNames` like this. No packages are used.

(The rlang package has a `set_names` function which is similar and it is imported by purrr.)

```
setNames(b, a)
```

giving:

```
Label 1 Label 2 
      1       2
```

The source of `setNames` is just this:

```
> setNames
function (object = nm, nm) 
{
    names(object) <- nm
    object
}
<bytecode: 0x000000001044d4b0>
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change `names` of `b` -

```
names(b) <- a
b

#Label 1 Label 2 
#      1       2
```

Answer (score 1):

We may use the `names<-`

```
`names<-`(b, a)
```